# Split up long C++ double literal into multiple lines

Tags: c++, vim, long-double

I'm implementing log_10(x) in terms of log_2(x) with the following formula
log_10(x) = log_2(x)/log_2(10).
I want to make this function generic (eg I would like it to work with could work with Boost's cpp_bin_float_quad) and, as far as I know, there's no great way to compute log_2(10) at compile time, so I just pasted in a long literal for 1/log_2(10). The following code works but I have some issues with it:

```cpp
template <typename T>
static inline T log(T x){
    T invlog2of10 = 0.301029995663981195213738894724493l;
    return invlog2of10*log2(x);
}
```

Issue 1: The literal is so many characters long that it makes vim slow and it breaks the syntax highlighting. Is there a standard compliant way to split this floating-point literal into multiple lines? Doing so would fix the syntax highlighting and then it'd be clearer how many digits there are in the literal.
Issue 2: Is long double really the highest precision I can use for this literal? Computing this constant at compile time would be much more ideal.

I tried putting spaces, newlines, and and backslashes into the floating-point literal similar to what can be done for long string literals. This did not work.

Comment: What is the type of `invlog2of10`?  This matters.

Comment: I'm assuming `long double` from the tag, but this really should be specified in the code.

Comment: on issue 2 you should give thanks if `long double` does more than simply satisfy the requirement that it be at least as precise as `double` .

Comment: Sorry, I edited it to include the type of invlog2of10. invlog2of10 should have as many digits as there is precision in T. Also, the code compiles now and the vim highlighting still breaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a backslash:

```
T invlog2of10 = 0.301029995663981\
195213738894724493l;
```

The backslash escapes the newline.

Comment: This is the error I get when trying this solution: error: expected ',' or ';' before numeric constant
  125 |                   4172321214581766l;

Comment: @ShawnMcAdam that error suggests that you have added some whitespace characters between these two lines.  Do not indent the second line - a number can not have spaces in the middle.